# Custom Domain option missing in Github

Tags: github-pages

My "Custom Domain" is missing! I go to my repository >> Settings >> Pages. Underneath the "Theme Chooser" option, I should be able to enter a custom domain, but there is no option there. Screenshot attached. [custom-domain-missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zw2CA.jpg) I have attached a screenshot. Am I missing a step? Do I need to add in the IP addresses first in my DNS? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

OK, I figured it out. You have to add gh-pages from the source option, and then /root. And the option comes up. Hopefully that will help some other noob out there!